# Handling function pointer with covariant types uniformly (how to call callbacks with derived types?)

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a `Task` class:

```
class Task;

using FinishedCallback = void (Task &);

class Task {
    public:
        // this function is implemented by derived classes
        // there are other virtual functions too
        virtual bool isFinished() = 0;

    private:
        std::vector<FinishedCallback> m_callbacks;

    protected:
        // these functions are called by derived classes
        void addFinishedCallback(FinishedCallback callback) {
            m_callbacks.push_back(callback);
        }

        void callFinishedCallbacks();
};
```

This class is the base class. I'd like to put as much implementation as possible into it. It has a `m_callbacks` vector, which stores the callbacks which are needed to be called when the task is finished (`callFinishedCallbacks()` does this).

Now, derive from this class:

```
class MyTask;

using MyFinishedCallback = void (MyTask &);

class MyTask: public Task {
    public:
        void addFinishedCallback(MyFinishedCallback callback) {
            Task::addFinishedCallback(reinterpret_cast<FinishedCallback &>(callback));
        }

        // when MyTask finishes, it calls callFinishedCallbacks
};
```

Here, the finished callback has `MyTask &` parameter, so I have to reinterpret_cast it. So my program has UB. (The reason of the `MyTask &` type is that I don't have to cast `Task &` to `MyTask &` in the callback - it is for convenience).

But, even my program has UB, it works (the only real problem I could have if `MyTask` had multiple inheritance). Is it possible to modify this program to remove UB, while retaining its main attributes:

- (compiled) code is small
- small amount of coding work needed, if one derives from Task
- no wrappers needed for callbacks

Answer (score 1):

**One idea** would be to make a slight change to how you write your callbacks.

1. Use `Task *` rather than `Task &` as the callback parameter type.
2. At the beginning of the callback, use `dynamic_cast` to turn the `Task *` into a pointer to the derived type (`MyType *`).

   ```
   void MyCallback(Task *task) {
     auto *mytask = dynamic_cast<MyTask *>(task);
     assert(mytask != nullptr);
     // use mytask from here on
   }
   ```

**Another idea** would be to use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP).

```
class BasicTask {
    public:
        virtual ~BasicTask() = default;
        virtual bool isFinished() = 0;
};

template <typename Self>
class Task : public BasicTask {
    private:
        typedef void FinishedCallback(Self &task);
        std::vector<FinishedCallback> m_callbacks;

    protected:
        void addFinishedCallback(FinishedCallback callback) {
            m_callbacks.push_back(callback);
        }

        void callFinishedCallbacks();
};
```

Then you'd derive your specific task types from Task like this:

```
class MyTask : public Task<MyTask> { ... };
```

This reduced the amount of code you have to write (because there's only one source code implementation of `addFinishedCallback`), but it runs the risk of generating more object code.  The optimizer and linker might be able to reign in that possibility.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! But that was the whole point to avoid this, as I've written it in the question :) Note, that task still can be a reference here, and `static_cast` can be used instead of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: I believe this fits your stated requirements:  compiled code is small, small amount of work is needed, and no wrappers are introduced.  The UB is eliminated and the casting is limited to the parameter itself rather than the entire function signature, so there are fewer things that can go wrong.  What requirement have I missed?  (And, yes, a static_cast would work here if there are no bugs in the implementation.)

Comment: "(The reason of the MyTask & type is that I don't have to cast Task & to MyTask & in the callback - it is for convenience)." Here, I meant that I'd like to avoid casting altogether. Not even once. I know, it's not a big deal, but it is not elegant to cast to MyTask. This casting should be handled by `Task`, it is just an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks for the other solution, I'll use it in the last resort, if no better solution exists.